# "Stream" tar action from remote server through Putty?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, tar

I am accessing a shared hosting account through Putty / SSH. 
The account is pretty full, 300 MB below its quota.
I need to make a full backup of all data present on the account. Creating a bzip2 file using

```
tar cjf archive.tar.bz2 directory/*
```

fails because there is not enough space for the tar.

Does anybody know a way to create a tar file and "stream" it to a local file on my PC? Through putty or any other SSH tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have cygwin, then you can just run something like this on your local machine:

```
ssh user@host 'tar cj directory' > /cygdrive/c/archive.tar.bz2
```

and it will put the tar archive in c:\archive.tar.bz2

If you don't have cygwin, you can do the same thing with [plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (part of PuTTY) from a command window;

```
plink user@host 'tar cj directory' > c:\archive.tar.bz2
```

(I'm assuming you're on Windows if you're using PuTTY - if you're on Linux, just run the ssh command)

Comment: Cheers @James. This seems to be doing the trick (still downloading, notice the slight difference in quotes): `'tar' cj directory > c:\archivename.bz2`

Answer (score 2):

Use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/).

Comment: Good point, but I would like to compress the data on server side into a tarball to save traffic. I think WinSCP can't do that. Still, the next best thing.

Comment: you wont get a tar achive, and you'll be copy unix files to a windows filesystem. That's not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Quotas are enforced on a per filesystem basis.  If /tmp has enough space available, there's a good chance you can use it.

To pipe tar through SSH:

`ssh server "tar -cf - /home/user" | tar xvf -`

Answer (score 1):

on unix/linux it's very easy to push a tar stream (or any stream) over the network.

PUSH: (if your logged into the machine where the data is)

tar zcvf - /wwwdata | ssh username@backupserver.org "cat > /backup/wwwdata.tar.gz"

PULL: (logged into your workstation for instance)

ssh  tar cf - -C sourcedir . | tar xvf -

ssh  tar cf - -C sourcedir . | cat > /backup/mywwwdata.tar

now, on windows, you maybe able to do this with the ssh that comes with http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Why would you `cat` data already being output to STDOUT?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using plink as a test to 'pull' the entire tree from my iphone via usb networking just to test it.

Works great!

```
plink user@host 'tar' --create --bzip2 --verbose / > x:\iphonebackup\iphone.tar.bz2
```

iPhone processor has teh slowness, so it comes in spurts.  But, it's working perfectly.

NOTE: Leave out the "--verbose" part for quiet/save bandwidth.  I included it so that I'd get something on my screen to let me know it was working right.  Spewing all that information would defeat the purpose of saving pipe/speed.  I only used it to confirm function.